# best encode decode for binary file in java and c#

Tags: c#, java, decode, binaryfiles

i know there is many types of encode and decode and from what i have read, base64 is a great choice when it comes to encode binary file (image, mp3, video).

Now, when it comes to decode, i will need to convert from the base64 and then get the string value. the process to get the string after decode, i will require to do like this (in c#): `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);`

here i noticed that i have several choices on what to use to get the string, such as ASCII, UNICODE, DEFAULT.

the real question in this post is if im using java to encode and c# to decode the binary file, what is the best solution/choice should i use? i have tried several method and some of the character could not be read thus gives out question mark symbol (?).

however, the most closer encode decode that could be read the byte is when im using this in Java: `String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(fileData, Base64.CRLF);` meanwhile in c# im using like this: `byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
            string returnValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);`

Still, there are several character that cannot be read. Does anyone have solution for this problem statement? any feedback is much appreciated. thanks for advance.

Comment: Why would you use base64 ? The purpose of base64 is to make the data easy to transfer when you can't use binary or aren't sure of the encoding transformation, by using a reduced set of characters. What are **your** needs ?

Comment: base-64 encodes arbitrary binary as a formatted string; the only decode you can do from there is back to arbitrary binary. ASCII (or other text encodings) encode an arbitrary string as formatted binary - *entirely* different (the reverse, in fact). It is not usually relevant to talk about base-64 and text-encodings in the same context, since they relate to radically different (inverse) scenarios...

Comment: [apache thrift](http://thrift.apache.org) see example [CSharp example](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/08/29/c-thrift-examples/) or [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). If you need only serialize/deserialize use apache-avro

Comment: @ajozwik serialization is a separate topic, really; since the OP mentions "binary file (image, mp3, video)", I don't think that applies here.

Comment: Is this a question about character sets, or encoding?

Comment: @DavidGrant this question more on to encode decode..is what im doing make sense?

Comment: @MarcGravell then what is your best suggestion for this? im trying to send image using java to the standalone application which it act as the server which im using c#.

Comment: @ajozwik no, no apache is required for this

Comment: @sara my "best suggestion" is, already mentioned (what 15 minutes ago?), to stop trying to treat an image/video as a string. It quite simply: isn't. The only time it is a string is if you have base-64 encoded it for transfer over a text-only protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that that input is "image, mp3, video", so: arbitrary binary. You then state that you're using base-64, meaning: for some reason you need to transfer / store this data as a string (note: transfer / storage as raw binary would usually be preferred - base-64 has overhead).

> Now, when it comes to decode, i will need to convert from the base64 and then get the string value.

There's the problem; there *is no string value here*. An "image, mp3, video" is simply not a "string value". What you *can* do is decode from the base-64 back to raw binary (trivial in either java or c#), but *that is all you can do*. If you needed a "string value" from raw binary, the only thing you can do is to re-encode it via base-64 (which would give you back what you started with), or some other base-n.

A text-encoding such as ASCII or UTF-8 only makes sense if the binary data is known to actually be text data stored in that encoding. You cannot use UTF-8 to "decode" binary that isn't actually UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

The thing about binary files is that they are *binary* (type `byte[]`). Most of the time you can not convert the bytes *directly* to a string (using `Encoding.GetString(byte[])`), because some of them may have values which can not be represented in a string (which is what you are experiencing).

Converting binary data to string using `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` to convert it to BASE64 doesn't make sense at all as you lose information when converting the binary information to string - you'd need to convert it directly to BASE64.

Converting a BASE64 string representation of a byte array to `byte[]` is OK - this gives you back the original binary data. However, converting this `byte[]` to `string` is not OK for the reason I've given above.

How BASE64 encoding is supposed to work is:

1. Get binary data as `byte[]`
2. Create BASE64 string from `byte[]`
3. Transfer BASE64 string
4. Create `byte[]` from BASE64 string
5. Continue working with `byte[]`

Comment: "as you lose information when converting the binary information to string" - that depends on *how* you do it; if you use base-64, no information is lost.

Comment: @MarcGravell im trying to transfer image file. i encode the image with base64 using java and transfer it to the c# and decode using System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData) then im doing like this System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes). am i still losing the data?

Comment: @sara yes; go back a step, so you get as far as `byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData)`, and **then stop**. The `byte[]` result from that ***is*** your image data. That is the image. If you want to save it as a file, then maybe `File.WriteAllBytes(path, data)`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: In the question, the code says `byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData); string returnValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);`. This conversion (the assignment of `returnValue`) can not be done without possible loss of information. However, I'll make an edit to make things clearer.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar indeed; the only sane / lossless thing that could be returned *as a string* would be `string returnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedDataAsBytes);` (or something trivially similar), which would give us back what we started with. I don't disagree with you there. I think the OP has some fundamental gaps in terms of what this data *is*... The point I was trying to make is simply that `byte[]==>string` is not *by necessity* damaging.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I agree with you - I hope I've made this clearer by the edit I've made.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get string after you decode your data, it implies that your data in somehow in text format.If this is the case you should have the knowledge of the file's initial encoding, such as UTF-8. Then you can properly decode the strings. If your program only transfer files from one place to another without doing anything with its content, you better leave them as you decode.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Convert string object (Java or C#) to byte array using UTF-8** (or some other, if you have a reason for that) encoding.
2. You now have binary data, UTF-8 encoded text to be specific. If you need to transfer it somewhere, which does not support raw binary data or UTF-8 text or if you don't want to worry about some characters having special meaning like in XML, **convert it to ASCII string using base64 encoding**.
3. **Do whatever** you wish with the ASCII string (base64 even allows some whitespace mangling etc) to get it to decoder.
4. **Convert ASCII string back to byte array with base64 decode**.
5. **Convert byte array back to string object (C# or Java) using UTF-8 encoding**.

If binary data or UTF-8 text is ok, you can skip steps 2 and 4. But 1 and 5 are needed, because in languages like C# and Java, string is "logical characters", it is not bytes you can store or transfer (of course it's bytes in memory, usually UTF-16 or UTF-32, but you should not care about that). It must be converted to bytes using some encoding. UTF-x are the only ones which don't lose any characters, and UTF-8 is most space-efficient if most characters are from "western" alphabets.

One special thing about base64 is, that while it is actually 7-bit ASCII characters, you can put base64 encoded text to C#/Java string object and back to base64 encoded byte array using any string encoding, since all string encodings in use are superset of 7-bit ASCII. So you can take image data, base64 encode it, and put resulting text to String object without worries about encodings and corruption.

Steps for binary files:

1. Get contents of binary file like PNG image file to byte array.
2. Same as step 2 above, except data is not UTF-8.
3. Same as step 3 above
4. Same as step 4 above
5. You now have byte array containing the PNG file contents from step 1.

Comment: can i use this steps to for the image file? i believe UTF-8 is only compatible when it comes to text and image/mp3/video file would loss its content when convert it to utf-8